# How can i convert Bitmap to memory stream?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, directx-9

I have a code in form1 constructor:

```
ConvertedBmp = ConvertTo24(newest.FullName);
```

The function ConvertTo24 is:

```
private static Bitmap ConvertTo24(string inputFileName)
        {
            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Bitmap bmpIn = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(inputFileName);
            Bitmap converted = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
            {
                g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
                g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpIn, 0, 0);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            return converted;
        }
```

The problem is how can i use the ConvertedBmp in this line:

```
backTexture = TextureLoader.FromFile(D3Ddev, @"D:\test.bmp");
```

TextureLoader have some properties and two of them are: Fromfile and it's getting device and string or FromStream and it's getting device and Stream.

I have the device object already but how can i use the ConvertedBmp(Bitmap type) with the TextureLoader ?

Comment: Is `TextureLoader` part of a library, and if so, which library?

Comment: TextureLoader is part of Microsoft DirectX.Direct3D and i'm using DirectX 9 version in this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitmap class has a method called Save() which accepts a Stream (for example a MemoryStream object) and an ImageFormat, use that. After saved the Bitmap into a MemoryStream you can use that with TextureLoader.

[Image.Save Method (Stream, ImageFormat)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

I get below code from here:
http://www.java2s.com/example/csharp/system.drawing/bitmap-to-memory-stream.html

```
public static MemoryStream ToMemoryStream(this Bitmap b)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            b.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return ms;
        }
```

Work for my need